# I want to detect if a JVM Class is a Kotlin class or not

Tags: reflection, kotlin

I want to do special functionality if I encounter a Kotlin class as compared to a generic Java class.  How can I detect if it is a Kotlin class?

I was hoping that calling `someClass.kotlin` would throw an exception or fail if the class wasn't Kotlin.  But it wraps Java classes just fine.  Then I noticed that if I do `someClass.kotlin.primaryConstructor` it seems to be `null` for all java classes even if they have a default constructor, is that a good marker?  But can that return `null` for a Kotlin class as well?

What is the best way to say "is this a Kotlin class?"

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Kotlin adds an annotation to all of its classes, and you can safely check for its existence by name.  This is an implementation detail and could change over time, but some key libraries use this annotation so it is likely to be ok indefinitely.

```
fun Class<*>.isKotlinClass(): Boolean {
    return this.declaredAnnotations.any {
        it.annotationClass.qualifiedName == "kotlin.Metadata"
    }
}
```

Can be used as:

```
someClass.isKotlinClass()
```

The class `kotlin.Metadata` is not accessed directly because it is marked `internal` in the Kotlin runtime.

Comment: Why not compare the class directly? `it.annotationClass == Metadata::class`

Comment: The class is not accessible, is `internal`

Comment: Ah. It seems to be accessible from Java. For example, I wrote this (unmerged) pull request for the Spring Framework: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/pull/1060/files#diff-244315b45582a5b7573a15644b16c373R48 (yes, they wanted it written in Java, eek).

Comment: Yep, Java doesn't respect the Kotlin idea of `internal`

Comment: Metadata is `internal` in Kotlin 1.2 but it is `public` in Kotlin 1.3

Answer (score 1):

While the other answer may work (possibly outdated), many reflection features will not work on file classes or generated classes (lambdas, etc).

However, there is a parameter in the @Metadata annotation that can tell you if the class is what you are looking for:

> A kind of the metadata this annotation encodes. Kotlin compiler recognizes the following kinds (see KotlinClassHeader.Kind):
>
> 1 Class 
> 2 File 
> 3 Synthetic class 
> 4 Multi-file class facade 
> 5 Multi-file class part
>
> The class file with a kind not listed here is treated as a non-Kotlin file.

```kotlin
@get:JvmName("k")
val kind: Int = 1
```

We can take advantage of this to make sure we are only getting real classes:

```kotlin
val Class<*>.isKotlinClass get() = getAnnotation(Metadata::class.java)?.kind == 1
```

I can confirm this works in 1.6.20